# SVG stroke, CSS animation: not all strokes moving in the same direction

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

The below animation is pretty straightforward, or so I thought. You will notice that one of the strokes, and only one, starts going backwards. I fail to understand why this is the case.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}
#path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 170;
  animation: animate1 5s infinite linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -16.4%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 87.5%;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -100%;
    stroke-dasharray: 170;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
        <a xlink:href="#">
            <path id="path2" fill="#000" d="M173,226h400v400H173V226z"/>
            <path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M108,171h500v500H108V171z"/>
        </a>    
    </svg>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help, appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Since you expressed the `stroke-dashoffset` as a percentage it's no longer resolved against the `pathLength` of the `path` element and instead is resolved as percentage of the viewport, so your keyframes are attempting to resolve inaccurately and flooring the math to do so as they go. Leaving as a comment since I don't have time to give a proper explanation at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total length of the path `path1` is `2000 px`

If you want to get 4 segments with 4 equal intervals, then the length of one stroke will be equal to one eighth of the total length:  `2000 / 8 = 250 px`

In this case, write stroke-dasharray = "250, 250"

Animation is achieved by reducing the `stroke-dashoffset` from`2000px` to zero

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}
#path1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 250;
  stroke-dashoffset:2000;
  animation: animate1 5s infinite linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate1 {
  
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 250;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
        <a xlink:href="#">
            <path id="path2" fill="#000" d="M173,226h400v400H173V226z"/>
            <path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="#000" d="M108,171h500v500H108V171z"/>
        </a>    
    </svg>
</div>
```

**SVG solution**

```html
<style>
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

</style>
<div class="container">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
        <a xlink:href="#">
            <path id="path2" fill="#000"  d="M173,226h400v400H173V226z"/>
            <path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="250,250" stroke-dashoffset="2000" d="M108,171h500v500H108V171z">
      <animate
        attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     from="2000"
     to="0"
     dur="5s"
     repeatCount="indefinite" />
   </path>
        </a>    
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander! That makes sense. Providing 2 implementation to boot is just really nice icing on the cake.